# Power bi cómo crear matriz con celdas de colores complejo

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Tengo una matriz donde las filas son los agentes y las columnas son los días de mayo, por ejemplo. En la matriz, hay un valor, llamémosle valor1.
Lo que quiero hacer es que si la columna (es decir, los días de la semana), son festivos (ya tengo la columna que me dice si son festivos o no) que se pinte toda la columna de gris. Además, si en los otros días hay algún valor1 que sea nulo, que se pinte de rojo.

Sé que existe la opción de Formato condicional > Color de fondo y puedes meterle medidas dax, el problema es que no sé qué medida construir, me salen errores recurrentemente.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.